# Find all solutions of the equation $\sin x-\frac{6}{x}=0$ for $x\in[0,12\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to solve the equation $\sin x-\frac{6}{x}=0$ for $x\in[0,12\pi]$.

I tried substituting $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and solving the quadratic but it did not lead to anything. [image]

It has 10 solutions but I do not know how to get the exact values.

Comment: You can't, at least in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: equations like this usually don't have closed form solutions. you have to refer to numerical or graphical methods

Comment: Here are some numerical results: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*sin(x)-6%3D0

Comment: You'll get 8 solutions, not 10.

Comment: you may notice that the solutions become closer and closer to an integer multiple of $\pi$ as $x$ becomes large.